# How can you restrict generic functions to prevent use of Arrays and Dictionaries?

Tags: swift

Is there any way to prevent a caller from passing an Array or Dictionary to this function, either with a constraint or with a code check?

```
internal class Decoder {

    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T {
        let decoder = try _Decoder(data: data)
        return try T(from: decoder)
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean you don't want `T` to be an `Array` or `Dictionary`? Why not?

Comment: Because the data structure of arrays and dictionaries are not compatible with the underlying encoder/decoder.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. An overload with a special runtime error is the best you've got.

```swift
extension Decoder {
  struct Error: Swift.Error { }

  func decode<T: Decodable & Sequence>(_: T.Type, from _: Data) throws -> T {
    throw Error()
  }
}
```

You might need more than one overload if you can't find a protocol that will cut it.

Comment: Jessy this is a great answer! I had been doing something similar hoping it was temporary but it gave an "ambiguous use of". Yours is precise enough that it works great and then throws the error - exactly what I wanted! BTW I didn't give you the -1 - I think this is a great answer. I think there may be a slight chance it stops a top level item that is not an array but implements Sequence, but I can live with that.

Comment: BTW - it works with just "Sequence", with "Decodable & Sequence" it causes a compile error on the call of "Value of protocol type 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols" With just Sequence it works beautifully.

Comment: You should only see that error if you try to decode a sequence of protocols, which is impossible anyway, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can constraint `T` like this:

```
 func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type,
                             from data: Data) throws -> T where T: AnyObject {
            let decoder = try _Decoder(data: data)
            return try T(from: decoder)
    }
```

This way Xcode won't let you pass arrays to that function. But probably you'll want to pass a custom protocol or class as generic constraint, because with `AnyObject` you won't be able to pass structs.

My suggestion is that you create (if you didn't yet) a custom `Decodable` protocol and pass it as `T` constraint:

```
protocol ModelProtocol: Codable {}

class BaseModel: ModelProtocol {

}

struct Model: ModelProtocol {

}

func decode<T: ModelProtocol>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws {
    let decoder = try _Decoder(data: data)
    return try T(from: decoder)
}
```

That way you would get what you need

```
let baz = try? decode(BaseModel.self, from: data)
let bar = try? decode(Model.self, from: data)
let foo = try? decode([Model].self, from: data) 
//Instance method 'decode(_:from:)' requires that '[Model]' conform to 'ModelProtocol'
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve the objective because as you say, it also prevents non-classes from being passed (which could possibly be achieved by adding an AnyClass to the constraint).